# How do I pass the user's server side request to the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-fullstack

I don't know if I phrased the title correctly, so sorry if it confused you.

I have two servers running (using different ports), one is my client side running on React, and the other one is my server side running on Express.
I'm trying to have the user log in via Steam, so I'm using the `passport-steam` library. Basically, when the user logs in on steam, it passes the user data to the server-side req session, but I need it to be on the client-side so it can access the data and load it on the website.

Here's some code if that helps

```
// /routes/auth.js
// /AUTH ROUTER

// GET Request the CLIENT will send to get their info
router.get("/user", ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  res.json(req.session.user);
  // returns undefined because their session is saved on the server side
});

// GET Requests used to sign in and authenticate
router.get("/steam", passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login" }), function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
});

router.get("/steam/return", passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login" }), async function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Comment: Then you can just simply put token (JWT/bearer) as response from server-side to client side as it's the proof of the user being authenticated?

Comment: can you show your code for `ensureAuthenticated `? It returns the user and you should pass it to the CB and then pass it to the response object. Check [this](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-steam/).